# Error "empty range in char class" when using var in regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to match a array of emails to an array of domains. I am currently running a problem with my regex:

> empty range in char class: /.*["@email-email.com"]$/ (RegexpError).

Here is what I am trying:

```
@emails.each do |email|
    @domains.each do |domain|
        if email =~ /.*#{domain}/
            puts domain
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You need to escape the square brackets and your dash, these characters have meaning within regular expressions. Take a look at this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161903/regular-expression-empty-range-in-char-class-error

Comment: Hmm, escaped all the symbols which got rid of the error. However I did not get any matches. Is the [" actually showing up in the regex? If so should I convert it to a string?

Comment: Yes, if you have the escaped square brackets in your regular expression then it is assumed that will be in what you are matching. What are you trying to match with that pattern ?

Comment: I don't have any brackets in my regex, nor in my source file so I don't know where they are coming from. I want to match email to domains. (ie: bob@test.com to @test.com

Comment: This, `/.*["@email-email.com"]$/`, is the pattern you have posted in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below would generate a hash of domain as the key and array of matching emails

`@domains.each_with_object({}) { |domain,hash| hash[domain] = emails.select { |email| email.ends_with(domain) } }`